# How to stop components adapting to the size of a JPanel that is inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, components, resize, size

The components inside a JPanel (which has a BoxLayout) are getting resized when there's lack of space.

The JPanel is inside a JScrollPane, but because of the fact that the components get resized, the scroll bar is useless.

The JScrollPane is also content inside a JTabbedPane by the way.

Setting a minimum size and preferred size to every component doesn't fix the problem:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
```

Any idea of how to deal with this?.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/7Nm7k81.png]

This is how I wan't it to look like, with a fixed size:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/hmqFKwg.png]

Comment: Not really understanding the problem. I see a vertical scrollbar so that appears to work. None of the panels are wide enough to need a horizontal scrollbar so that also appears to be working. I would guess you are trying to have all the panels fill the space available so you could use a `GridBagLayout` with a "fill" constraint. Or nest a panel with a `GridLayout` to the "PAGE_START: in a panel using a `BorderLayout`. Post an [mre] if you need more help. Create a simple demo with panels with hardcoded sizes and different colors to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: it'ss hard to tell from an image, but it looks like your inner `JPanels` should contain a `JLabel` for the image and two non-editable `JTextAreas` for the text.  Another alternative is to use a `JTable` with a `JLabel` and two non-editable `JTextAreas`.

Comment: Just added more info about the problem. I wan't the track boxes to be of a fixed size, so that they can't get resized. Because, if they get adapted to the avalaible space, the scroll bar makes no sense, and the text may not be visible. Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: (1-) 1) That is NOT an [mre]. We are not interested in your application, only code that demonstrates the problem. You were given a simple suggestion on how to simplify the code to demonstrate your problem. 2) Your comment makes no sense. If the panel is created properly a scrollbar will appear when required so you can scroll to see text that may not currently be visible. Your first image has a problem because you are manually setting the preferred size. Don't set the preferred size. You have been give suggestions on using a different layout manager to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: *I wan't the track boxes to be of a fixed size,* - the BoxLayout respects the maximum size which is not set for a JPanel, so a panel will grow to fill the space. You can override the `getMaximumSize()` method of your panel to return the "preferred size".

Answer (score 1):

I took what information was visible in your image and created an example Swing GUI that displays the same information.

[image]

I don't know how my code is different from your code.  I placed a `JLabel` and two `JTextAreas` inside of a download `JPanel`.  I created a main `JPanel` to hold the download `JPanels`.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MusicDownloadGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MusicDownloadGUI());
    }
    
    private final MusicDownloadModel model;
    
    public MusicDownloadGUI() {
        this.model = new MusicDownloadModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Music Download");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JScrollPane createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        for (Track track : model.getDownloads()) {
            panel.add(createDownloadPanel(track));
        }
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        return scrollPane;
    }
    
    private JPanel createDownloadPanel(Track track) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(track.getAlbumCover()));
        panel.add(label);
        
        JTextArea titleArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
        titleArea.setEditable(false);
        titleArea.setText(createTitleArea(track));
        panel.add(titleArea);
        
        JTextArea artistArea = new JTextArea(3, 25);
        artistArea.setEditable(false);
        artistArea.setText(createArtistArea(track));
        panel.add(artistArea);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private String createTitleArea(Track track) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(track.getTitle());
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append("Download -- ");
        builder.append(track.getPercentDownloaded());
        builder.append("%");
//      System.out.println(builder.toString());
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    private String createArtistArea(Track track) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Artist: ");
        builder.append(track.getArtist());
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append("Duration: ");
        int minutes = track.getDuration() / 60;
        int seconds = track.getDuration() % 60;
        builder.append(minutes);
        builder.append(" minutes, ");
        builder.append(seconds);
        builder.append(" seconds");
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append("Quality: ");
        builder.append(track.getQuality());
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
    public class MusicDownloadModel {
         
        private final List<Track> downloads;
        
        public MusicDownloadModel() {
            this.downloads = new ArrayList<>();
            
            Track track = new Track("Bandaga", "Otra Copa", "0.6 kbytes", 216);
            track.setPercentDownloaded(42);
            addDownload(track);
            addDownload(new Track("Bandaga", "Ahora Dice Que Me Ama", "0.6 kbytes", 198));
            addDownload(new Track("Camin", "Tu Nombre (feat. JC Reyes, El Daddy) - Remix", 
                    "0.6 kbytes", 246));
            addDownload(new Track("Bandaga", "Como Tu", "0.6 kbytes", 205));
            addDownload(new Track("Pablo Alboran", "Liueve Sobre Mo Jado", "0.6 kbytes", 228));
        }
        
        public void addDownload(Track track) {
            this.downloads.add(track);
        }

        public List<Track> getDownloads() {
            return downloads;
        }
            
    }
    
    public class Track {
        
        private int percentDownloaded;
        private final int duration;
        
        private final String artist, quality, title;
        
        private final BufferedImage albumCover;

        public Track(String artist, String title, String quality, int duration) {
            this.artist = artist;
            this.title = title;
            this.quality = quality;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.percentDownloaded = 0;
            
            this.albumCover = new BufferedImage(40, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = albumCover.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, albumCover.getWidth(), albumCover.getHeight());
            g.dispose();
        }

        public int getPercentDownloaded() {
            return percentDownloaded;
        }

        public void setPercentDownloaded(int percentDownloaded) {
            this.percentDownloaded = percentDownloaded;
        }

        public int getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public String getArtist() {
            return artist;
        }

        public String getQuality() {
            return quality;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public BufferedImage getAlbumCover() {
            return albumCover;
        } 
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A BoxLayout respects the minimum and maximum sizes of components added to it.

By default a JPanel doesn't have a maximum size so it grows to fill the space available.

So one solution is to override the `getMaximumSize()` method of the panel to be equal to the preferred size.

a) Run the code as is below to see the default behavour. Click the "Add Row" button to see how the layout changes as rows are added.

b) Then repeat after changing the `getMaximumSize()` method to use the preferred size.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoxLayoutRow extends JPanel
{
    private int rowIndex;
    private JPanel rowPanel;

    public BoxLayoutRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        rowPanel = new JPanel();
        rowPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(rowPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );

        add(new JScrollPane(rowPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        add(addRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        addRow.addActionListener((e) -> this.addRow());
    }

    private void addRow()
    {
        rowIndex++;

        JPanel row = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize()
            {
                return super.getMaximumSize();
                //return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };

        row.setAlignmentX(0.0f);

        row.add( new JLabel("Row: " + rowIndex) );
        row.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        rowPanel.add( row );
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayoutRow");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new BoxLayoutRow() );
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowUI());
    }
}
```